# Why isn't an overflow exception raised?

Tags: c#, powershell, clr

The following runs fine without error and `diff` is 1:

```
int max = int.MaxValue;
int min = int.MinValue;
//Console.WriteLine("Min is {0} and max is {1}", min, max);
int diff = min - max;
Console.WriteLine(diff);
```

Wouldn't then all programs be suspect?  *a*+*b* is no more the sum of *a* and *b*, where *a* and *b* are of type `int`.  Sometimes it is, but sometimes it is the sum* of *a*, *b* and 2*int.MinValue.

* Sum as in the ordinary English meaning of addition, ignoring any computer knowledge or word size

In PowerShell, it looks better, but it still is not a hardware exception from the add operation.  It appears to use a `long` before casting back to an `int`:

```
[int]$x = [int]::minvalue - [int]::maxvalue
Cannot convert value "-4294967295" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, overflow checking is turned off in C#. Values simply "wrap round" in the common way.

If you compiled the same code with `/checked` or used a `checked { ... }` block, it would throw an exception.

Depending on what you're doing, you may want checking or explicitly *not* want it. For example, in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) we have overflow checking turned on by default, but explicitly turn it off for `GetHashCode` computations (where we expect overflow and have no problem with it) and computations which we know *won't* overflow, and where we don't want the (very slight) performance penalty of overflow checking.

See the [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) and [`unchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) pages in the C# reference, or section 7.6.12 of the C# language specification, for more details.

Comment: iAPX architecture doesn't offer built-in overflow checking for the Add operation?

Comment: @OldGeezer: I wouldn't like to say exactly how it's implemented lower down - but unchecked arithmetic *is* very slightly faster in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

When not specified, .NET will not check for numeric overflows when doing operations on numeric data types `int`, etc.

You can enable this by either building in checked mode (passing `/checked` into the compiler arguments), or [use `checked` in a code segment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx):

```
checked
{
    int i = int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```